# C# Load DLL Fails

Tags: c#, dll, plugins

I am writing a Plugin System in C#.

```
int Length = Directory.GetFiles(@".\Plugins", "*.dll").Length;
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@".\Plugins", "*.dll"))
{
    string PluginDLL = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + file;
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(PluginDLL);
    
    foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyPlugin)))
        {
            IMyPlugin plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IMyPlugin;
            
            if (!plugins.Any(item => item.PluginName == plugin.PluginName) && 
                !plugins.Any(item => item.PluginVersion == plugin.PluginVersion))
            {
                plugins.Add(plugin);

                ToolStripMenuItem pluginToolStripeItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
                pluginToolStripeItem.Name = plugin.PluginName + "ToolStripMenuItem";
                pluginToolStripeItem.Text = plugin.PluginName;
                ansichtToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(pluginToolStripeItem);
                //this.startseiteToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.StartseiteToolStripMenuItem_Click_1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the First .dll is loaded successful.
When it comes to the second .dll the PluginDirectory is set successful,
but the "asm" stays the one from the first .dll

Why is the asm not changed when I call it with the new PluginDirectory.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards
Stefan K

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221124/discussion-on-question-by-stylezzxdmg-c-load-dll-fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now. I generate a List of the Assemblies first and then I go through the list. I don't know why it doesn't worke when I create the instance,... directly in the foreach where I get the Assembly.

Thats the solution now.

```
List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Plugins\\";

foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
    allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));

foreach (Assembly asm in allAssemblies)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyPlugin)))
            {
                IMyPlugin plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IMyPlugin;
                string[] pathParts = asm.Location.Split('\\');
                int pathLenght = pathParts.Length;
                plugin.PluginLoadedPath = pathParts[pathLenght-1];

                if (!CurrentPlugins.Any(item => item.PluginName == plugin.PluginName) && !CurrentPlugins.Any(item => item.PluginVersion == plugin.PluginVersion))
                {
                    CurrentPlugins.Add(plugin);
                    ToolStripMenuItem pluginToolStripeItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
                    pluginToolStripeItem.Name = plugin.PluginName + "ToolStripMenuItem";
                    pluginToolStripeItem.Text = plugin.PluginName;
                    ansichtToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(pluginToolStripeItem);
                    //this.startseiteToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.StartseiteToolStripMenuItem_Click_1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```